# Atomic Increment of Counter ensuring MAX value boundary in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I have a table with 2 columns `Id` & `Counter`. I'm trying to find a way to atomically increment the counter, ensuring it doesn't exceed some MAX value.

My goal is to **NOT USE** transaction if possible.

Here's what I came up with so far:

```
DECLARE @MAX_VALUE INT = 100

UPDATE MyTable
SET Counter = CASE 
                  WHEN Counter < @MAX_VALUE THEN Counter + 1
                  ELSE @MAX_VALUE
              END
WHERE Id = 123 
  AND Counter < @MAX_VALUE
```

What I'm struggling with is to find a confirmation if this will handle concurrency ? If 2 concurrent sessions try to update counter which currently has 99 value (@MAX_VALUE - 1), then I need to ensure that after both are done Counter's value does not exceed `@MAX_VALUE`.

**MORE CONTEXT**

This counter is incremented & decremented on demand, ranging from 0 to MAX_VALUE. I figured decrement part, increment is what I'm struggling with. In regards to **NOT USING** transactions - as I said *if possible* not that it's a hard requirement to not use them.

Comment: Use a `SEQUENCE`?

Comment: *"My goal is to NOT USE transaction if possible."* Then you are going to suffer race conditions, with no transaction and locking of your row(s). That is very likely to be undesired behaviour.

Comment: This counter is incremented & decremented on demand. I don't have much experience with `SEQUENCE`, will it handle both ?

Comment: A `SEQUENCE` goes in one direction. You don't even mention the need to *lower* the value in the above; this is starting to smell like an [XY Problem](//xyproblem.info), or you have missed out on a lot of context.

Comment: @ThomA updated OP with some more context.

Comment: *" I figured decrement part"* The solution for both will be identical, just instead of `-1` it would be `+1`, so why not use the solution you have?

Comment: @ThomA good point, for decrement I end up using optimistic concurrency with retries, want to see if there is another way.

Comment: Use a transaction, *lock* the row until you are "finished" with it. Why do you *not* want to use a transaction?

Comment: shouldn't UPDLOCK or similar be enough to avoid the problems with getting concurrent updates?